# Which one is better among DynamoDB and AWS ElasticSearchService for querying and storing logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm building a GUI tool for querying logs and looking for a cheaper option. DDB will fetch logs from an S3 bucket using lambda whereas ES will get the same logs streamed from CloudWatch. The thing is my queries are gonna be simple, not complex ones so I'm inclining towards DDB. Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed access patterns that can be queried using the partition key and sort key, staying within the [limits of querying on a sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions), then DynamoDB is certainly a very good option. There are other factors, like size of the data, and number of records in a partition.

If you can do most of the filtering with the above, but need to further reduce the data based on values outside the key you still can use DynamoDB, but your milage may vary on how good it is. It becomes very dependent on data size and filtering complexity.

There is certainly a point where the complexity of the queries goes beyond what DynamoDB is designed for. At that point ES is often a good answer. Keep in mind that ES isn't a fully managed service, and it's a paid for the time it's running, regardless of use. I tend to try to avoid these types of services when I can, but if cost is not a significant factor for you, and you feel comfortable managing the ES cluster, then ES is a great option for advanced querying.